# How to test the client in the absence of API?

Tags: php, http, mocking, phpunit

I decided to write a client that sends http requests to the API. There are 3 types of requests: GET, POST, PUT. We need to write unit tests using phpunit, which will allow us to test the functionality without writing an API. My first thought was to use a mock object. Having read enough literature, I can’t understand in any way how to do this. As I understand it, I need to make a stub for the API wherever my requests go. Please tell me in which direction to move in order to solve the problem.

```
<?php

namespace Client;

class CurlClient implements iClient
{
    private $domain;

    public function __construct($domain = "http://example.com")
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;
    }

    public function getAllComments()
    {
        $ch = curl_init($this->domain.'/comments');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $comments = curl_exec($ch);

        $comments = json_decode($comments);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $comments;
    }

    public function addNewComment($data)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($this->domain.'/comment');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_exec($ch);

        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);

        $statusCode = (string)$statusCode;
        $statusCode = (int)$statusCode[0];

        curl_close($ch);

        return $statusCode == 2 ? true : false;
    }

    public function updateComment($id, $data)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($this->domain.'/comment/'.$id);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_exec($ch);

        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);

        $statusCode = (string)$statusCode;
        $statusCode = (int)$statusCode[0];

        curl_close($ch);

        return $statusCode == 2 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple mock example using `phpunit`. `phpunit`'s mocking capabilities are extensive, for more info [phpunit documentation - test doubles](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php)

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

  // Use the getMockBuilder() method that is provided by the   
  // PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase class to set up a mock object
  //  for the CurlClient object.

class CurlClientTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testAddNewComment()
    {
        // Create a mock for the CurlClient class,
        // only mock the update() method.
        $client = $this->getMockBuilder(CurlClient::class)
                         ->setMethods(['addNewComment'])
                         ->getMock();
        $map = [
          ['hello', true],
          [123, false]
        ];

        $client->method('addNewComment')->will($this->returnValueMap($map));

        $this->assertEquals(true, $client->addNewComment('hello'));
        $this->assertEquals(false, $client->addNewComment(123));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this test actually testing though? There is no user code being run. It seems to me like it tests if phpunit can make a mock correctly, that doesn't really help.